# Call Receiver makes my app "force close"

Tags: android

it all works fint till i answer the phone call,then a few seconds later and i get a "force close" message...any idea what is wrong?

```
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    PhoneStateListener imPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener();
    telephony.listen(imPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
    Intent intent1=new Intent("android.intent.action.Checker");
    intent1.putExtra("phoneNr", phoneNr);
    context.startActivity(intent1);
}
```

oh and by the way, how can i promise that my call reciver always work first even if the app is in the background?

Comment: What error is showing up in the Log Cat?

Comment: The emulator makes a lot of problems for me,so i use my Galaxy instead...

Comment: @Theter : So? Get the logcat from your Galaxy.

Comment: @Theter : Connect it using USB and run DDMS to watch the logcat output. Either that or install a logcat app on your Galaxy - just search the Play Store for the word logcat.

Comment: Okay there you go...it says that:java.lang.runtimeException error reciving broadcast intent...intent.action.PHONE_STATE...has extars.

it also says "...has leaked intentReciver...that has origanly registerd here...are you missing a call to unregister?"

Answer (score 0):

```
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
PhoneStateListener imPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener();
telephony.listen(imPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Without seeing the logcat it's hard to say for certain but you shouldn't be doing the above.

`TelephonyManager` is a system service and calling `listen(...)` is registering a permanent reference to your `imPhoneListener` object.

A `BroadcastReceiver` exists only as long as the code in `onReceive()` is being executed. This means once `onReceive()` exits, your `imPhoneListener` is no longer a valid object but `TelephonyManager` still holds a reference to it.

When you answer the phone call, you change the phone 'state' and the `TelephonyManager` will attempt to notify the non-existent `imPhoneListener` object. Something has to break here.

Get rid of those three lines as they effectively do nothing of any purpose for your `BroadcastReceiver` anyway - I'm not even sure what you're trying to acheive there.

Comment: @Theter : "...has leaked intentReciver...that has origanly registerd here...are you missing a call to unregister?" - Yes, as I mentioned in my answer the "leaked" receiver is your `imPhoneListener`. You say it now doesn't work at all - do you have an `<intent-filter>` registered in your manifest? Your receiver must be being called somehow otherwise `onReceive()` would never execute.

Comment: <receiver android:name=".CallReciver" >
            <intent-filter >
>                    

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: @Theter : **<intent-filter > >** - I'm assuming that second `>` is a typing error?

Comment: @Theter : Sorry, I don't know why it would have stopped working. Those three lines of code would have nothing to do with your receiver being called or not. As long as you have the permission READ_PHONE_STATE, that intent-filter should mean your receiver will be called.